# Problema com mapeamento no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Olá, tenho a seguinte estrutura de projetos usando Spring Boot e estou tendo problemas es criar os beans deles:

projeto1: com.portal (serviço spring-boot)

```
contem os @Controllers
```

projeto2: com.service

```
contem os @Service e @Component
```

projeto3: com.model

```
contem os @Repository
```

O projeto portal não conversa com o model somente com o service, que por sua vez conversa com o model.

Mas na hora de subir o serviço do projeto1 com.portal, da um erro dizendo que não consegue acessar uma classe do projeto com.model, que acredito que esteja correto pois o portal não tem acesso as classes do model.

Existe alguma forma de contornar isso no spring boot ou estou fazendo a estrutura de projetos errado?

Comment: ao meu ver a estrutura está "correta", mas você não deveria devolver o model, e sim um dto

Comment: oi @LucasMiranda é exatamente isso que faço, sempre retorno uma DTO, porém mesmo assim o spring esta reclamando, percebi que isso ocorreu devido a exclusão de um pacote, pois coloquei o model como dependência do service, e quando coloco o service como dependência do portal excluo o pacote do model, a partir dai começa dar erro, se tiro a exclusão funciona

Answer (score 1):

O problema era, porque ao injetar o pacote do service no projeto do portal, estavamos excluído o pacote do model, pois o mesmo é injetado no service e não quero que o portal enxergue o model, ocasionando do spring não encontrar as classes do model.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>service</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>model</groupId>
                <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

a solução foi excluir o pacote do model da forma acima e adicionar no scopo em tempo de execução dessa forma quando o sistema for executado o spring consegue encontrar as classe

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.officersoft.basic-service</groupId>
        <artifactId>basic-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.officersoft.basic-model</groupId>
                <artifactId>basic-model</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.officersoft.basic-model</groupId>
        <artifactId>basic-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor solução, mas foi o que encontramos.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como fazer isso diferente, fique a vontade em opinar.